# Get total count using group by having count > 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for multiple spots on a cat patterns in a table.

```
select spot_pattern, count(*) from cat_pattern group by spot_pattern having count(*) > 1;
```

Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to get this info?

```
select * from temp_new_template_pattern 
where vin_pattern in (
select vin_pattern
from temp_new_template_pattern 
group by vin_pattern 
having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked, but from the question I thought the desired result was either "I found a total of 8 duplicates" or "yes, there are duplicates".  (Although you can get those results by changing the "outer" SELECT above.)

Comment: I tried not to make the question confusing. I did find 8 total but i needed them in a count not 2 of each.